# Paginating an array of arrays (no db) without a limit

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, pagination

I have a 'display all' functionality on my site. Currently there are 7 sub-folders that are iterated through to display categories. (Empty folders are not shown, and more sub-folders may be added).

I **don't want to set a limit** [of images] per page, i just want to show all of the images for each folder on a different page.

Despite extensive googling and experimenting, the best i could come up with was a number of html pages being displayed, all appended one to the other, on one long page. (ugh!) I've been at it now since last night so i'm a bit fed up.

I have stripped back my displayall.php to it's basic functionality. Here's what it looks like at the moment (with no pagination):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/bootstrap_combined.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/style.css'>";
<title>Gallery Display</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">  
<header>
<h1>The Ultimate Gallery Compiler</h1>
<div id='menu'><a class='head' href='index.html'>Upload Photo</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class='head' href='gallery.html'>Browse Gallery</a></div>
</header>
<!---end header-->
<div id='content'>
<h2>Gallery: All Images</h2>
<?php
//$pages = isset($_GET['page'])?intval($_GET['page']-1):0; //get page
//$pageno = $_REQUEST['page'];
//compile an associative array

$subfolder= array('Fashion/LifeStyle'=>'1', 'Music/Video'=>'2','Sport/Leisure'=>'3','Electronics/Technology'=>'4','Pets/Animals'=>'5','Health/Beauty'=>'6','Other'=>'7' ); 
$carray=count($subfolder);       

// iterate through the sub directories, and count them
$files = "images/*/*";
$sub=0;
foreach(glob($files) as $file) 
    {   
        $sub++;  //total number of images
    }



foreach ($subfolder as $subf=>$value)  
{   
    $folder = "images/".$value."/";
    $link = 'displayall.php?'.$value;
    $mykey= $subf;
    $counter = 0;
    // Open the appropriate subfolder, and display its contents.
    if ($dir = opendir($folder)) {
        $images = array();
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir))) {
            if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            $counter++;
            $images[] = $file; 
            }
        }
        closedir($dir);
    }

     //don't show empty categories

    if ($counter!== 0){ 
    echo "<input type='hidden' id='current_page'/>"; 
    echo "<input type='hidden' id='show_per_page' />"; 
        echo "<h3>Category: ".$mykey."</h3><br>";  //display heading
        echo "<h4>There are " .$sub. " photos in the <a href='gallery.html'>Gallery</a> to date</h4>";  //display total overall
        echo '<div id="multi">';

        foreach($images as $image)  {           
            echo '<span class="gallery"><img src="';
            echo $folder.$image;
            echo '" alt="" width="200" height="auto" /></span>';    //show images
        }

    echo '</div>';
    //$num= $pages +1;
    echo "<br><strong>".$counter. " photos</strong><br>";  //display total per category
    echo "<span id='pageNo'>Page Number: ".$value."</span><br>";

    echo "<a href = ".$link. ">Next</a>";

    echo "<br><br><hr><br>";  //put space and a line between the categories
    };
    //$pageno++;


}   
?>
<footer>
<p class='foot'>&copy; Copyright 2015-2016 MMA2 Rachel Gallen, Ysabel Pheifer and Rebecca Merrigan.</p> 
</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

(It can be viewed [here](http://multimedia.dcu.ie/~gallenr2/CM267Assignment2/displayall.php))

Any help on the pagination would be appreciated. All the tutorials seem to be either mysql related or dealing with a single array. V frustrating!

(open to php, jquery, javascript or bootstrap solutions!)

Thanks and happy chrimbo

Rachel

edit: former edit removed

Comment: $_GET['page'] is a query string parameter.  e.g. index.php?page=foo

Comment: You dont look even close to coding what you say you want to code, so this question just looks like a bad specification. At SO we do **not work from specifications**

Comment: @RiggsFolly i posted the above code stating that it was stripped back to basics and it does what its supposed to do, which is display all images. I got rid of unworking code. Theres no need to be so high and mighty about SO - everyone runs SO - theres no 'We' - and its Christmas.. lighten up

Comment: Show us your attempt at what you really want it to do. Maybe its not so far away from where you want to be.

Comment: @RiggsFolly its on my server somewhere i'll have to find it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your page is looping through all the subfolders, it looks like an attempt was made to only display subfolder being specified by the querystring parameter `page`.  This can be accomplished with a minor edit to your PHP:

```
<?php 
$pages = isset($_GET['page'])?intval($_GET['page']):1; //get page
//$pageno = $_REQUEST['page'];
//compile an associative array

$subfolder= array('Fashion/LifeStyle'=>'1', 'Music/Video'=>'2','Sport/Leisure'=>'3','Electronics/Technology'=>'4','Pets/Animals'=>'5','Health/Beauty'=>'6','Other'=>'7' ); 
$carray=count($subfolder);       

// iterate through the sub directories, and count them
$files = "images/*/*";
$sub=0;
foreach(glob($files) as $file) 
    {   
        $sub++;  //total number of images
    }



    $value = $pages;  

    $folder = "images/".$value."/";
    $link = 'displayall.php?page='.$value + 1;
    //$mykey= $subf;
    $arrayKeys = array_keys($subfolder);
    $mykey = $arrayKeys[$value];
    $counter = 0;
    // Open the appropriate subfolder, and display its contents.
    if ($dir = opendir($folder)) {
        $images = array();
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir))) {
            if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            $counter++;
            $images[] = $file; 
            }
        }
        closedir($dir);
    }

     //don't show empty categories

    if ($counter!== 0){ 
    echo "<input type='hidden' id='current_page'/>"; 
    echo "<input type='hidden' id='show_per_page' />"; 
        echo "<h3>Category: ".$mykey."</h3><br>";  //display heading
        echo "<h4>There are " .$sub. " photos in the <a href='gallery.html'>Gallery</a> to date</h4>";  //display total overall
        echo '<div id="multi">';

        foreach($images as $image)  {           
            echo '<span class="gallery"><img src="';
            echo $folder.$image;
            echo '" alt="" width="200" height="auto" /></span>';    //show images
        }

    echo '</div>';
    //$num= $pages +1;
    echo "<br><strong>".$counter. " photos</strong><br>";  //display total per category
    echo "<span id='pageNo'>Page Number: ".$value."</span><br>";

    echo "<a href = ".$link. ">Next</a>";

    echo "<br><br><hr><br>";  //put space and a line between the categories
    };
    //$pageno++;



?>
```

### Summary of Changes:

I un-commented the `$pages` variable so it pulls from the query string parameter.

It also looks like you tried to send that query string via the `$link` variable, but the format was not correct.  I updated that to `$link = 'displayall.php?page='.$value + 1;`

Finally, I removed the for loop and set `$value` to the current `$page` parameter so only one subfolder would be shown on a page.

**Changes Made After Edit #1**

The ternary operation on `$pages` was setting the value to 0, resulting in the error when looking for `/images/0/`.  Changed to `$pages = isset($_GET['page'])?intval($_GET['page']):1;`

Added an array to handle the keys from the associative array, since the querystring is using integer values instead of category names.
`$arrayKeys = array_keys($subfolder);
 $mykey = $arrayKeys[$value];`

*You might want take a long hard look at passing string values instead of integer values to $page.  It'll make for better SEO, better folder names, and removes the need to have an associative array to map the integers to a category name and back again.*

### Final Notes:

This certainly has room for expansion, you might consider error checking to make sure the value is inbounds and the folder is valid.  Previous and next links, and quick navigation to a specific page number might also be useful.

Hope that helps!

Comment: i'll give that a whirl!

Comment: i need the subfolder as subf bit cos i display the category name - how do i get around that?

Comment: What are the names of the subfolders in your directory structure?  Are they just numbered 1 through 7?

Comment: yes, but the category names are different, thus the associative array

Comment: the error i got was that there was no images/0/ which there would never be anyway, numerically or text-wise

Comment: The associative array is unnecessary.  You could do a regular array with the category names as strings and access it with `$mykey = $subfolder[$value]`  or if it helps keep track of which folder belongs to what index, you could keep the associate array and retrieve the key by looking at the position in $value.  As for the error, you'd need to change $pages so it isnt 0 in the ternary operation.  I'll update my answer in a moment.

Comment: i made it associative so i could a) keep track of category and b) know what folder to file into

Comment: just saw the edit now. thanks. its close. the next links don't work and it shows empty pages but its close

Comment: Surely thats part of the CM267 homework... ;-)  Make sure you have `$link = 'displayall.php?page='.$value + 1;` in the code.  Looks like its missing.

Comment: i have it in. still have problem on last page. and empty pages show up where i didn't have them before

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98728/discussion-between-adam-konieska-and-rachel-gallen).